# Types of applications in Facebook API notifications

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a simple script to pull all my facebook notifications. I filter them based on type using the "application" field, and display only the relevant ones.

Is there any way to find out which application types exist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `application` field returns under the `notifications` object but I'm going to assume is the identification number for the application.  So assuming this, you could just make another call to the Graph for that particular ID using the `application` object:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application

You'll note you can access the `app_type` field available there.

If you were just wanting to know what possible types exist, I would assume they are similar to the ones you pick for yourself when submitting an application to the app center.  Check out your application settings - somewhere there should be a place to pick out what type of application yours is.  I would expect any results from your Graph calls to be similar to those.